# How do I convert functions that use C++ pass-by-reference into C?

Tags: c++, c

I have a piece of code that is written in C++ and need it in C. I converted most of it but I can't figure out how to convert C++ pass-by-reference in functions to C code, i.e.

Example:

```
int& a;
```

it is used in some function as a input variable:

```
void do_something(float f, char ch, int& a)
```

When I compile it with C I get compiler errors. Whats the correct way to replace the pass by references in C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to do this in C is to pass by pointer:

```
void do_something(float f, char ch, int* a)
```

Also when using a in `do_something` instead of

```
void do_something(float f, char ch, int& a)
{
   a = 5;
   printf("%d", a);
}
```

You now need to dereference `a`

```
void do_something(float f, char ch, int* a)
{
   *a = 5;
   printf("%d", *a);
}
```

And when calling `do_something` you need to take the address of what's being passed for a, so instead of

```
int foo = 0;
d_something(0.0, 'z', foo);
```

You need to do:

```
int foo = 0;
d_something(0.0, 'z', &foo);
```

to get the address of (ie the pointer to) foo.

Answer (score 1):

Because references are not available in C, you'll have to pass a pointer instead:

```
void do_something(float f, char ch, int *a)
```

And then in the body of the function you must dereference it in order to get or modify the pointed to value:

```
*a = 5;
```

Assuming that `x` in an `int`, and you want to call the function, you use the `&` operator to get its address (convert it to an `int *` pointer):

```
do_something(f, ch, &x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest equivalent is a pointer:

```
do_something(float f, char ch, int* a)
```

Having done this, you'll need to change `a` -> `*a` everywhere within the function, and change calls to the function to pass `&a` instead of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

The "easy", but **inadvisable**,  way is to get help from a helper pointer variable and a #define
<sup>feel free to downvote this answer! I would if I could :)</sup>

Turn this

```
int foo(int &a) {
    a = 42;
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

into

```
int foo(int *tmpa) {       /* & to *; rename argument */
    #define a (*tmpa)      /* define argument to old variable */
    a = 42;                /* no change */
    /* ... */              /* no change */
    return 0;              /* no change */
    #undef a               /* "undo" macro */
}
```

**Note: the introduction of the #define must be done with care**

Comment: I wouldn't advise someone to use such a `#define`, unless he is very lazy or doesn't want to remember that `a` is a pointer.

Comment: I will actually upvote it because it's smart and explains the concept, and we agreed that it's inadvisable.

Comment: Creative answer, but it doesn't take care of the change in calling convention (as you would need to change code calling this to use &). I won't downvote, but I won't upvote because this really shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

There's no equivalent to C++ references in C.
However, you could use pointers. They are however variables with their own address, whereas C++ references are just aliases.

```
function do_something(float f, char ch, int* a)
```